# Using query string in include_once function

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

How can we use query string in include_once function

like this:

**include_once 'model/edit.php?id=$inf';**

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: thank u,and i've another one doubt

Comment: can we call a function anchor tag

Comment: @user2310192 First explain your first doubt, than move to another

Comment: can we call a function in controller through a Anchor tag in view

Answer (score 4):

No you cannot. Parameters are reserved to URL's. But you can emulate the effect which adding a parameter to the URL would have:

```
$_GET["id"] = $inf;
include_once 'model/edit.php';
```

Comment: thank u ...Another one doubt can we call a function in controller through a Anchor tag in view

Comment: @jee I don't understand what you mean. Ask a new question where you show what you exactly mean.

Comment: @jee As it has helped you, click please on the green bordered form left from my answer to accept it

Comment: <a href="controller/controller.php/db()?mode=edit & id='<?php echo "$info[id]";?>')"><img border=0 alt="edit" src="edit.jpg ">                                                   how to call function db() in controller class

Comment: @jee I think you have misunderstood how to program. I am unable to explain this correctly I think.

Comment: would u pls send me any link to understand how to prog..

Answer (score 0):

If you use include_once 'model/edit.php' then after this code you can use variables that are available in your script

edit.php

```
<?php echo $x; ?>
```

main.php

```
 <?php $x = "it works"; include_once 'edit.php'; ?>
```

check this code and you will understand. This code prints "it works".

Answer (score 0):

$inf = '1';

include_once 'model/edit.php;

There is no point on adding query string in include_once function. If you declare the variable before the function, then you can still access $inf in the included file directly.

Comment: k ...i've another one doubt  can we call a function in controller through a Anchor tag in view

Comment: Yes you can do so. You have to write : <a href="<?php echo base_url('controller/products')?>">Products</a> . Here product is the function in the controller.

Comment: call like this i got an error(call to undefined function base url)                                                                                                                                                   <a href=" <?php echo base_url(controller/db )?> ?mode=edit & id='<?php echo "$info[id]";?>')">